# Finding a cell with a specific value and applying a class to a cell in the same row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ranking table with specific Elo ratings for each player. Depending on their Elo rating I want the player's name to be a specific color based on their rank. I have been using the code below:

```
if (parseInt($("td.data-rating").val()) > 100) {
  $(this).closest("tr").find("td.data-name").addClass("important");
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hx4ph2fk/6/)
why does this code not work? Am I using "this" incorrectly?

Comment: Table cells don't have values, form elements do. You'd need to use .text() or .html()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues:

- The `this` keyword refers to the `Window` object
- Only `HTMLInputElement` have values, the use of `.val()` is incorrect
- You must iterator over each of the `<td>` elements to set the classList

This should work for you:

```js
$(function() {
  $("td.data-rating").each((i, el) => {
    if (parseInt(el.textContent) > 1000) {
      $(el).closest("tr").find("td.data-name").addClass("important");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.important {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="data-name">Player 1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="data-rating">1200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="data-name">Player 2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="data-rating">1150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="data-name">Player 3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="data-rating">1000</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

$("td.data-rating") will return array so .val will not work for it. you should use each function for that. Try below one.

```
$("td.data-rating").each(function (index) {
if(parseInt($(this).text()) > 1100) {
$(this).siblings().eq(0).addClass("important");
}
});
```

Comment: it actually returns a jQuery object - not an array.

Comment: I have edited my answer. please try this now. And sorry for syntax error if any in code.